# Column sumif on an unknown range of rows

Tags: excel, sum, range, sumifs

Quick query on something which I am positive must be straightforward, but is starting to drive me spare.

I want to SUM a column on which I define the range. However, I don't actually know the range. This will be running week-to-week, month-to-month. I get the data from a 3rd party program. I will be pasting that data into this s/sheet; however, I don't know how many rows I will have per column at any given point. The number could be 500, or 15000.

This is what I currently have, which is fine:

`= SUMIF(DataExtrGoesHere!A2:A999, "0", DataExtrGoesHere!I2:I999)`

However, it is a touch amateurish, and I may receive data that falls outside that 999 row range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the whole column (assuming there is nothing further down you don't want included). SUMIF typically uses the "used range" only, so that shouldn't be any less efficient

`=SUMIF(DataExtrGoesHere!A:A,0,DataExtrGoesHere!I:I)`

Comment: Well gee, that was embarrassingly straightforward. So defining the entire column is as simple as removing the numberic row references...well I'll be...